# Получить текст конкретной строчки

Tags: javascript

```js
const Lines = (el, l, lines = [], last = 0, s = 0) => {

  el.append(cl = document.createElement('div'));
  el.textContent.split("").forEach(v => {
    cl.innerHTML += v;
    last != (last = cl.offsetHeight) && s++;
    lines[s] = (lines[s] ?? '') + v;
    if(lines[l+1])
      cl.remove();    
  });

console.log(lines[l]);
};

Lines(text, 3);
window.onresize = _ => Lines(text, 3);
```

```css
#text {
 white-space: pre-wrap;
 max-width: 40%
}
```

```html
<div id=text>    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
 Praesentium nemo dolores debitis, maxime quia ipsum quasi 
officiis id libero tenetur autem similique iure itaque optio quis beatae minima! Libero, eaque!
</div>
```

Ни как не удается выхватить текст конкретной строчки. На выходе получаю текст но он то обрезан сначала, то сканца. Как мне решить это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В моем случаи вытаскивает

```
tur adipisicing elit.
```

Вместо

```
consectetur adipisicing elit.
```

Comment: какой результат ты ожидаешь для твоего примера

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем это строчка: `last != (last = cl.offsetHeight) && s++;`, это ведь просто Boolean посреди кода.

Comment: В цикле, каждый символ поочередно добавляю в блок. last - запоминает высоту, если в последующем цикле после того как добавили сивол. Высота меняется, значит текст был перенесен на новую строчку. Правильней использовать scrollHeight, но и с ним тоже самое.

Comment: Добавила скриншет

Comment: почему для `Lines(text, 3);` ожидается `consectetur adipisicing elit.`?

Comment: На моем экране, это третья строчка. Все верно

Comment: А переменная 's' это порядковый номер строчки

Answer (score 1):

Придумал такой алгоритм:

1. Рзабиваем текст по пробелам
2. Объявляем массив `line` и складываем туда по одному слова из разбиения
3. Создаём временный `div`, куда каждый раз вводим объединение всех слов из `line` и смотрим на его ширину. Стили у `div`-а такие, чтобы при добавлении и удалении не было видно этого визуально. Не использовал `display: none`, т.к. тогда не будет размера у `div`-а, а так можно будет настроить ему такие же стили как у основного `div`-а и более корректно определять допустимую ширину и прочие данные
4. Пока ширина меньше чем у основного `div`-а, то просто продолжаем добавлять слова. Если ширина станет больше чем у основного `div`-а, то объединяем все слова, кроме последнего в одну сроку и добавляем в массив строк
5. Последнее слово сразу становится первым словом для следующего предложения
6. После окончания цикла смотрим, если `line`, не пустой, значит осталось последнее предложение и его просто добавлем в массив `lines`
7. Т.к. количество строк может меняться постоянно, то при отсутсвии строки под нужным индексом, просто возвращается последняя строка

```js
const getLine = (target, index) => {
  const lines = [];
  const separatorSymbol = ' ';
  const words = target.textContent.trim().split(separatorSymbol);
  const targetWidth = target.offsetWidth;
  
  const tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
  tempDiv.style = 'visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: fit-content';
  document.body.append(tempDiv);
  
  let line = [];
  
  for (const word of words) {
    line.push(word);
    
    tempDiv.innerHTML = line.join(separatorSymbol);
    
    const currWidth = tempDiv.offsetWidth;
    
    if (currWidth <= targetWidth) continue;
    
    const lastWord = line.pop();
    
    lines.push(line.join(separatorSymbol));
    
    line = [lastWord];
  }
  
  if (line.length !== 0) lines.push(line.join(separatorSymbol));
  
  tempDiv.remove();

  return lines[index] ?? lines[lines.length - 1];
};

console.log(getLine(text, 3));
window.onresize = _ => console.log(getLine(text, 3));
```

```css
#text {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  max-width: 40%
}
```

```html
<div id=text>    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium nemo dolores debitis, maxime quia ipsum quasi officiis id libero tenetur autem similique iure itaque optio quis beatae minima! Libero, eaque!
</div>
```

Код может показаться рабочим, но это далеко не так. Алгоритм будет неправильно работать например если вручную расставлять переносы строк или изменить правило переноса в основном `div`-е или ещё что-то. Универсального способа не придумал, но конкретно под эти правила можно этот алгоритм использовать

А ещё не нравится постоянно добавлять и удалять `div` из `DOM`-а, наверное точно зная шрифт и размеры каждого символа, можно просто вычислить ширину. Для небольшой оптимизации можно ещё объявление `tempDiv` и назначение стилей вынести за пределы `getLine`, чтобы каждый раз не создавать его

Comment: Переносы строк не учитываются

Comment: Как я понимаю, пробелы тоже не учитываются

Comment: @Лена Если расставлять вручную, то да сломается алгоритм. Но если вставить текст без переносов строк, чтобы само переносилось, то учитвывается. Пробелы должны учитываться, т.к. я использую `join` с пробелом. Пиграйтесь с изменением размера экрана, код для таких настроек рабочий